# MySQL database Reports using Views

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, report

im creating one view that will return a series of row-count from different tables and schemas instead of creating reports using crystal reports ... etc .. \

just concerned about querying many tables using count(col) and where clause.

what is the down side of this approach ??

a little snippet from the view im creating

```
SELECT  ccwc.`Status` , COUNT('status') AS 'RowCount'
FROM ccwc
GROUP BY ccwc.status
 UNION
SELECT 'WC_Total' ,
COUNT(Id)
FROM `ccwc` 
union 
select 'WC_Exceeded' ,COUNT(Id) from ccwc where Attempts = 3
union 
select 'WC_No_Attempts' ,COUNT(Id) from ccwc where Attempts = 0 
union 
select 'ccEmp Count' , count(*) from cc_emp_lite
```

**NOTE : this view will be used by a winforms C# application for about 100 clients connected to MySQL server**

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a problem in querying the database in this manner to construct a view. The effects you are alluding are highly negligible.